# What is the mathematical terminology for wanting the maximum value of a variable before the equation's answers become complex?

Tags: linear-algebra

What is the mathematical terminology for wanting the maximum value of a variable before the equation's answers become complex? I'm not sure what to google or read so that way I can solve what I'm looking for.

The example problem that I have is the following:

I have the formula: x^(1/2) = y + x/100

I calculated that the largest value for y before the answers come back as complex numbers is y=25

in formula: x^(1/3) = y + x/100 I calculated that the maximum y can be is y = 20*3^(1/2)/9

in formula: x^(1/4) = y + x/100 I calculated that the maximum y can be is y = 3*25^(1/3)/4

in formula: x^(1/5) = y + x/100 I calculated that the maximum y can be is y = 4*2^(1/2)/5^(3/4)

The way I'm doing it is really time consuming and inefficient, I want to find out if there is a trick to calculating the numbers that I want, but I don't know what the math "word" or phrase is for what I'm trying to do so I can't find any instructions or do any extra research on my own.

Basically, for the formula: x^(1/z) = y + x/100
I want z to be positive integers only and I want to have a formula with z and y that will spit out the maximum value of y for that particular z value.

I'd really appreciate if someone can point me in the correct direction for making a method or formula to get the values that I'm looking for.

Comment: The maximum value of $y=\sqrt{x}-\frac{x}{100}$ for non-negative $x$ is indeed $25$, happening when $x=2500$.  If you use the real cube root then  $y=\sqrt[3]{x}-\frac{x}{100}$ can be arbitraily large when $x \to -\infty$, but for non-negative $x$ the maximum is as you say $\frac{20\sqrt{3}}{9}$ when $x=\frac{1000\sqrt{3}}{9}$.  You can find these taking the first derivative and setting it to $0$ and then checking the sign of the second derivative

Comment: Youre optimizing. Yes?  There is no proper order on the complex numbers so there is no maximum complex solution.  Maximums can only be real. So youre looking for a real value and youre looking for a maximum.